# Bot commands see if a parameter is an int

Tags: discord.py

Right now, I have this block of code. I want to make it so that the script knows if `hour` is an integer. `isnumeric()` doesn't work because it doesn't count negative integers. Thanks in for answering

Note: This is not in a class.

````
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def utc(ctx, hour):
    if(hour < 12 or hour > -12):
            timezones[ctx.message.author.id] = int(hour)
    else:
        ctx.send("The UTC command is for telling Sterling how many hours away from UTC you are. You can also use negative numbers.")```
````

Comment: Try: `async def utc(ctx, hour: int):`

Comment: Use function annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands, by default receive the parameters as strings, to convert it to an integer you can use discord.py
s [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=converter#converters) or manually convert it to an integer or float.

Using converter

```py
async def utc(ctx, hour: int):
```

Manually converting

```py
async def utc(ctx, hour):
hour = int(hour)
```

### References:

- [Converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=converter#converters)